# How to import a .rtf file to silverlight 4 richtextbox?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

I have a .rtf file and want to put it in a richtextbox in silverlight 4. Unfortunately we do not have .rtf property in silverlight 4 richtextbox, we only have .xaml.

So what i did is to create a FlowDocument, than load the .rtf to this FlowDocument, then format it to xaml. then assigned it to richtextbox. But i got a argumentexception.

How to import a .rtf file to silverlight 4 richtextbox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an ugly solution so far, use a FlowDocument to change the format from rtf to xaml. Then remove the attributes not accepted in SL4 richtext box, codes like below. It works but I hate it.
I want to know is there a better solution.

```
        string xaml = String.Empty;
        FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
        TextRange range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
            {
                sw.Write(from);
                sw.Flush();
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                range.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
            }
        }


        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

            range.Save(ms, DataFormats.Xaml);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                xaml = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        // remove all attribuites in section and remove attribute margin 

        int start = xaml.IndexOf("<Section");
        int stop = xaml.IndexOf(">") + 1;

        string section = xaml.Substring(start, stop);

        xaml = xaml.Replace(section, "<Section xml:space=\"preserve\" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste=\"False\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">");
        xaml = xaml.Replace("Margin=\"0,0,0,0\"", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Hmm... seeing that Silverlight doesn't support Flowdocument at all this is a bit confusing.

Comment: yes, you are right. Silverlight doesn't support Flowdocument, what I did is using FlowDocument in a webservice, and then silverlight can talk to the webservice

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the free [VectorLight Rich Text Box](http://www.vectorlight.net/controls/rich_textbox.aspx) control instead.

Comment: i checked the api of vectorlight richtextbox,  seems do not surpport rtf directly.

Comment: Oh yes, Vectorlight uses only XML richtext format, not RTF. Similar names, but different format.

Answer (score 0):

I need to do something similar (haven't done it yet ...)

I came across [NRTFTRee](http://nrtftree.sourceforge.net/examples.html), a C# RTF parser, which should port to silverlight.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/nrtftree.aspx

http://nrtftree.sourceforge.net/examples.html