# How to Load or Bind RTF file and dispaly it in Silverlight RichTextBox or RichTextBoxOverflow

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, rtf, silverlight-5.0

I´m writing my first application in Silverlight and I want to load text from RTF File and display it in RichTextBlock Control.

In this Silverlight control is not *Text* property or *LoadFile* property like was in WinForms Rich TextBox.

Please does anybody know how to load or bind some RTF file and visualize it in Silverlight without external toolkits??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import a .rtf file to silverlight 4 richtextbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314754/how-to-import-a-rtf-file-to-silverlight-4-richtextbox)

Comment: Please, this has been asked more than once already, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[silverlight]+rtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight does not support the RTF format.  The Silverlight `RichTextBox` only has a Xaml property to which you can assign rich text that is already in Xaml format.

In order to load RTF you would need to code to load and parse the RTF file into a Xaml string suitable for assignment to the `RichTextBox`.  There is no simple way to do this, even with third party the help like [NRTFTree](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11306/NRTFTree-A-class-library-for-RTF-processing-in-C).  You would still need to walk the generated tree to encode it to Xaml.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer. I was afraid about it, but I see there is no other chance. I assume that the same situation is for **RichTextBlock** too. Am I right?

Comment: Yes the two are basically the same control where Box is editable.